# How to debug VB 6 binaries in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vb6

I used to debug VB 6 binaries using VS 2005 few years back. Now I am trying to do the same in VS 2015 but I am not able to. Could anyone please tell me step by step how can I debug VB 6 binaries in VS 2015?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer, but I doubt that it's possible.

Comment: `I used to debug VB 6 binaries using VS 2005`   I am pretty sure that is not true

Comment: I followed this link and I am not able to find point 3 in Visual Studio 2015 which is Go to the project properties and select the “Configuration Properties->Debugging” property page and enable unmanaged debugging.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/11/09/debugging-vb6-binaries-in-visual-studio-net/

Comment: @Plutonix please refer the below mentioned link and I am sure you are able to debug VB6 binaries using either 2005 or 2008 Visual Studio. If you need any help let me know I can help. But I need help here is to debug on VS2015. 
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/11/09/debugging-vb6-binaries-in-visual-studio-net/

Comment: @user9963680: Did you do the steps mentioned in the link? If you can compile your VB6 code with your VB6 IDE, it would be much easier to debug it from within from VB6 IDE

Comment: Its probably Debug > Attach to Process ?

Comment: I've done this; I'll look up the instructions and post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VB6 project's Project->Properties->Compile, check "Compile to Native Code," "No Optimization" and "Create Symbolic Debug Info."

[image]

In Visual Studio 2015's Debug->Options, check "Use Native Compatibility Mode":
[image]

At runtime, in VS2015, attach to the process containing your VB6 executable. At this point, you should be able to set breakpoints and step through the code.